# xarray plot sparse data

Tags: python, plot, mask, python-xarray

Xarray uses pcolormesh for plotting. For example 2D data, but where 1 axes is not continuous pcolormesh will interpolate values. The nice thing from xarray is that it is "coordinate aware", i.e. it does not just plot like imshow but the real dimensions are used.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

x = np.random.randn(1000, 100)
y = np.hstack([np.arange(0, .1, 0.01) + i for  i in range(100)])
z = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
da = xr.DataArray(x.T, dims=("z", "y"), coords={"y": y, "z": z})
da.sel(y=slice(1, 4)).plot()
```

This is an example that will illustrate the problem. The y dimension is not continuous, it goes from 0.0 till 0.1, 1.0 till 1.1, ... n.0 till n.1. Is there a way to mask the values where there is data like [1] without resampling for every data point. I would like to prevent to add just all data points on the y dimension in between and add nan values, because there are more data points without data than data points with data.

Imshow did not solve the problem, since imshow is not aware of the "jumps" in the y dimension and just plots it as an image (what it is supposed to do, so no bug there).

I know that pcolormesh is used to interpolate between values (i.e. pcolormesh actually uses the coordinates to fill the white space inbetween, where imshow uses the cols and rows as color value [2]).

[1] https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quadmesh_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quadmesh-demo-py

[2] https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_grids.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-pcolormesh-grids-py

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I based my question based on the added example, so not sure what to add extra. I will add the import statements though.